# External Libraries (i.e. google play services), multiple versions of same library

Tags: android

I am trying to debug some errors I am having and one thing i am looking into is versions.   I can see that there are multiple versions of the same library such as "play-services".  Is it safe to just delete the older version and work with one?  I am not sure how it got like that.

Updated image showing play services.
[image]

Adding gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1" //should be at least 9.0.0
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Is it safe to just delete the older version and work with one?" -- you need to fix your module's `build.gradle` to pull in the version that you want.

Comment: but of course it may be not possible ... fx you are using: libraryA which is using libraryBv8, libraryC which depends on libraryBv10 and libraryBv8 and libraryBv10 are not compatible ...

Comment: I'm not seeing any play services in that image. Please show your Gradle file

Comment: Updated original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, they either didn't get deleted from your Gradle file when you switched versions, or you have them both currently listed as dependencies.

In either case, get rid of one.